# Should I make new table for storing user's address in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite, rails-activerecord, normalization

I have created a rails app and
my "users" table goes like this

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "email"
t.string   "password_hash"
t.string   "password_salt"
t.integer  "country_id"
t.integer  "state_id"
t.integer  "pincode"
t.string   "address"
t.string   "phone_no"
t.float    "latitude"
t.float    "longitude"
```

Other tables `states , country , posts`

Associativity:

```
user has_many :posts
user belongs_to :state
```

I have a `"states"` table for maintaining state names and other stuffs.I have a `"posts"` table in which each user can have multiple posts.

Clearly I have more focus on location attributes of the user, also I need to frequently access these attributes while rendering posts of a user.

So, should I fragment location related attributes into a new table `"addresses"`?

Each user has only one address.

I feel this one right but then I need to perform lengthy linking to access those attributes from `posts views`

Ex. to access state,

```
<% @state = State.find(Address.find(User.find(@post.user_id).address_id)).state_id).name%>
```

So, what should I do fragment users or just keep as it is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your business logic, creating table 'addresses' could be good, because in future your `users` can have more then 1 address.

From `sql` point you should make new table `addresses` but I am against building your tables because some `rule` of normalizing your `db` model. In your case `address` will not hurt much your `db`

For now you can keep your addresses inside `user` record, it will not harm your database, and will speed up your rendering time (even if it is by some milliseconds).

You have to find balance in `rendering` your views and `normalizing` your `db`. You model will be more resilient to further changes if you add `addresses` table. Implementing new features, or anything related to `users` and theirs `addresses`.

All in all it depends from your implementation, business model, requirements, and much more. You have to find balance that best fir your needs

Comment: Thanks man!. I always find the normalization a bit confusing with maintaining the balance.Do u have any suggestions over resolving this dilemma ! I think I should go for new "addresses" table.